# sql inner join two tables to fetch data via date range query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to query data from two tables namely `"tbl_tmpdtr"` and `"tbl_employee"` using date range to compare in the `tbl_tmpdtr` field namely in_out `datetime().` i have two input type="date" in my view as i pass it on my controller `{ $this->input->post('from_date');` `$this->input->post('to_date') }` to be used in my model check out the code below.

```
public function view_emp_dtr($a, $b)
{
    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_tmpdtr.id, tbl_tmpdtr.userid, date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, tbl_tmpdtr.status, tbl_employee.emp_id, tbl_employee.emp_lname, tbl_employee.emp_mname, tbl_employee.emp_fname, tbl_employee.emp_gender, tbl_employee.civil_status, tbl_employee.dob, tbl_employee.street, tbl_employee.barangay, tbl_employee.city, tbl_employee.province, tbl_employee.emp_contact, tbl_employee.spouse_lname, tbl_employee.spouse_mname, tbl_employee.spouse_fname, tbl_employee.spouse_gender, tbl_employee.relationship, tbl_employee.address, tbl_employee.spouse_num, tbl_employee.jobtitle_id, tbl_employee.store_id, tbl_employee.username, tbl_employee.password, tbl_employee.hiredate, tbl_employee.emp_status, tbl_employee.Image FROM tbl_tmpdtr INNER JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id WHERE in_out<='$a' AND in_out>='$b' GROUP BY tbl_tmpdtr.userid');

    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
        $data[]= $row;
        }
    return $data;
    }
}
```

my problem: the variable $a and $b are considered as columns;

Comment: fixed it i just used double quotes not singles quotes at the start and the end of the query, wondering what would be the difference cuz a new problem came out, no data was pass on to my foreach variable

Comment: You can answer your own question too

Comment: no i cant.. been solving this for 3 hours already..  i tried var_dump($a, $b) and the data was correct but the num_rows, it was zero. zero result? i already tried the code in my sql phpmyadmin(wamp) and i got the right result

Comment: So you didn't get your answer or what

Comment: no i didn't uchiha itachi/sazuke

Comment: i'm so mad at my self, you are right Uchiha i solved it my self. just added "tbl_tmpdtr" like this "tbl_tmpdtr.in_out" and so tbl_tmpdtr.in_out>='$a'. I'm gonna close this question already.

Comment: Great.Good to go....